# Animate parts of child components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a hard time understanding how animate components in React when it involves elements within child components. To set the stage, I have:

1. A button group component that contains some buttons.
2. A navigation component that contains some button groups. The navigation component creates arrays of button names and callbacks and then passes them to button group components as props.

Lets say the user takes some action on a page that will change the nav. More specifically, I want to fade out one of the buttons from one of the button groups in the nav.

I'm familiar how to use `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` and would think to use this in this case, but the tricky part is that the navigation component is the the thing that owns the animation trigger, and the button group component is the thing that owns the button that needs fading. When the navigation component re-renders, it throws away the old button group from the DOM and builds an entirely new one which means the old button group never has the opportunity to fade its button out.

Questions:

- Am I using the wrong abstractions here? If I want to fade out the button based on nav state, does the button have to belong to the nav and not in some child component?
- When the nav re-renders and new props are given to the button group, why does the button group get trashed and rebuilt rather than the existing one just getting a propsWillChange call?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it sounds like your child button group components shouldn't need to re-render.

If you're iterating over an array of name/callback pairs to build the buttons, make sure each button is being given a unique `key` attribute; maybe the name, if that is unique. That will give React a way of identifying which buttons to add or remove and which to leave in place.

With that, your `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` should work as expected.

Comment: The buttons do use a unique `key`. But it appears to me as if the whole button group is being re-rendered when the nav re-renders. How do I prevent this? Can I give the button group a `key` to tell React to reuse it? I'm not actually iterating over button groups, so I didn't think it would allow for this.